# Firebase Service Lifecycle

Tags: android, firebase

When Firebase Service receives a `RemoteMessage`, and the app has previously been killed by swiping it away, what must I do so that the app will still process the message?

It's a data message, so the behaviour is to process and not put to the GUI as a notification.

Comment: you app will receive data message in onMessageReceived method even if app is close

Comment: @UsmanRana that is not true, if app is in background Firebase handles notification by itself and skips the onMessageReceived

Comment: @mhenryk please read the question, he is using "data message" and for that onMessageReceived is called in both cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Below solution works in old Google Play Services (i.e. 11.0.2), newer ones like (11.6.0) have `handleIntent` declared as `final` making this solution no longer valid.

---

You have to override `handleIntent(Intent)` without calling `super.handleIntent(Intent)` in it. The problem with this approach is that the `RemoteMessage` object was not created. I personally create it myself like this:

```
RemoteMessage message = new RemoteMessage.Builder(FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken())
```

and pass the data into the map and then to `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage)` myself (this is obviously optional, you don't need that object at all).

This is obviously not the best approach but it was the only way I found that allowed me to build the notification on my own or ignore it completely.

Answer (score 1):

When a firebase message arrives, android OS ( precisely perhaps google services) broadcasts MESSAGING_EVENT intent.

```
<action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
```

You can implement a broadcast receiver having intent-filter filtering for above intent and in it's onReceive() method, your appropriate service should be started (if not running). Only broadcast receivers have capability to respond irrespective of its application's running status.

Comment: set as `<receiver android:name=".receiver.MyReceiver" android exported="true"><intent-filter><action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/> <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /><action android:name="com.me.app" /></intent-filter></receiver>` but am not getting the notification if swiped away.

Answer (score 0):

You may register a background daemon service, but i think it will be terminated too when user swiping it away, so basically there is no way to  do that, you should handle this as if it's a Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the task in the `onDestroy` method to process the message in background as an async service.

Your app's async service will always be running in background by listening to `BroadcastReceiver` and then once task is done you can `finish` the activity to kill the app

Comment: After swiping it away and then sending a FireBase notification immediately, it does not even go to the `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)` method. How do I make it call that method even after swiping it away?

Comment: If you register your fireBase notification service as an async task(using `BroadcastReceiver`) that runs in background and on push notification from
 fire base it should get triggered and start processing the message.

For Reference see GCM, Push Bullet etc...

Comment: set as `<receiver android:name=".receiver.MyReceiver" android exported="true"><intent-filter><action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/> <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" /><action android:name="com.me.app" /></intent-filter></receiver>` but am not getting the notification if swiped away